# Python if block executes if the condition expression evaluates to -1

Tags: python, if-statement

I wrote a method to convert a date string to a date in python. When I get the date from an external method, the millisecond precision is lost, whereas when I do the casting within the method the precision is preserved. Could someone let me know what is the problem here? Thanks a lot!

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone   

def getUTCTimeFromString(date_string):
    #allow time with Z in it
    if date_string:
        if date_string.find('Z'):
            date_string = date_string[:len(date_string)-1]
        return datetime.strptime(date_string,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
    return None

def getStringFromDate(dateObject):
    return dateObject.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

#Method being tested
# Input 2012-02-27T05:32:10.607Z
def getEasternTimeFromString(date_string):
    if date_string:
        if date_string.find('Z'):
            date_string = date_string[:len(date_string)-1]
        local_date = datetime.strptime(date_string,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
        utc_date = getUTCTimeFromString(date_string)
        print 'utc date from external method --> '+getStringFromDate(utc_date)
        print 'utc date calculated locally -->' +getStringFromDate(local_date)
        return utc_date.astimezone(timezone('US/Eastern'))
    return None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
if date_string.find('Z'):
    date_string = date_string[:len(date_string)-1]
```

The problem is that [`string.find()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) returns `-1` if the target is not found. Since -1 is not zero, the `if` statement is true, and then your code chops off the last character of the string (whether it was a `Z` or not).

You're doing this truncation twice in the case of `utc_date` and once in the case of `local_date`, thus your different results.

I would suggest:

```
if date_string.endswith('Z'):
    date_string = date_string[:-1]
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I'm fairly new to python. Didn't realize this would break. Btw, I used `date_string.count('Z')` instead of the find `date_string.find('Z')` which works fine in my case.

Comment: @Jay: Even better would be `date_string.endswith('Z')` which checks for the presence *and* location at the end of the string. Also, `date_string = date_string[:-1]` is sufficient to truncate the last character.

Comment: Suggestions taken and implemented. Thank you Greg!

Comment: Why not `date_string.rstrip("Z")`?

Comment: @kindall: That would work too. I usually only use `rstrip()` when truncating whitespace, but as you say it works with arbitrary sets of characters.